# multiple selectors with document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

Hot to get multiple selectors values using `document.querySelectorAll`?

I need to get URL inside selectors.

```
<div class".myClass"><a href="link1.html"></a>
<div class".myClass"><a href="link2.html"></a>
<div class".myClass"><a href="link3.html"></a>
```

I'm trying to use the follow but it is not working:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log (x[i].childNodes[1].href);
}
```

Comment: this is NOT `<div class".myClass">` correct HTML! You might want to writhe `<div class="myClass">`

Comment: Ehm, .. its not `class".myClass"` but `class="myClass"`. Then use `querySelectorAll(".myClass")`

Comment: In the html above you have dots in the class names (remove them, but leave them in the selector) and you've not closed any of the divs.

Comment: @Archer Yeah, sorry forgot the dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your HTML:

1. the class should be changed from: `<div class".myClass">` to `<div class="myClass">`
2. you forgot to close the `<div>` with `</div>`
3. if you use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over all the elements.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
x.forEach(function(element, index){
    console.log(index + ': -> ' + element.children[0].href);
});
```

```html
<div class="myClass"><a href="link1.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link2.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link3.html"></a></div>
```

if you don't want to use forEach() (you still need to change point 1 and 2) the code will look like so:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");

for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    console.log(i + ': -> ' + x[i].children[0].href);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"><a href="link1.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link2.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link3.html"></a></div>
```

**Append string to url**:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");

for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].children[0].href = x[i].children[0].href + '&item1=yes';
    console.log(i + ': -> ' + x[i].children[0].href);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"><a href="link1.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link2.html"></a></div>
<div class="myClass"><a href="link3.html"></a></div>
```

Comment: are you brazilian? How to append data into grabbed url?
I tried to use `x[i].children[0].href) = x[i].children[0].href) + '&item1=yes'` but did not works.

Comment: @PLazzo no I'm not Brazilian. Have a look at the updated answer **append string to url**

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for assigning class or any atrribute to elements in Html is this:

```
<div class="myClass">
```

You don't need a `.` to assign a class name to an element but need it in case of accessing like you did above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use class="someClass" syntax (`class="myClass"`).
2. The childNodes index starts from 0. Use `x[i].childNodes[0].href`
3. The div elements don't have corresponding closing tags.