# In pure JS, I am trying to set two similar classes but with different numbers or to set the same class to two different elemnts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to set the same class `imagens-giratorias` to two elements or to set `imagens-giratorias` and `imagens-giratorias-2`. The class worked in first element, and the same class stopped of animating in the second element.

**[I provide the JSFiddle at the end.]**

Check the [@rafaelcastrocouto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242389/rafaelcastrocouto)'s original code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524483/8041366. If you prefer reading the complete code here, here is the code taken from there, but with a bit modified:

```
var counter = 1;
var div = document.querySelector('.imagens-giratorias');
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll('.imagens-giratorias img');

var showNext = function () {
  counter++;
  if (counter > 3) counter = 1;
  div.classList.remove('imagem1', 'imagem2', 'imagem3')
  div.classList.add('imagem'+counter);
};

for (var img of imagens) {
  img.addEventListener('animationend', showNext);
}
```

And small CSS snippet:

```
<div class="section-2">
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="imagens-giratorias imagem1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section-3">
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="imagens-giratorias imagem1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="section-3">
  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="imagens-giratorias-2 imagem1">
    </div>
</div>
```

- 1st solution, that same original code above I am referring.
- 2nd solution:

```
var div = document.querySelector('.imagens-giratorias, .imagens-giratorias-2');
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll('.imagens-giratorias img, .imagens-giratorias-2 img');
```

- 3rd solution

```
var div = document.querySelector('[class^=imagens-giratorias]');
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=imagens-giratorias] img');
```

- 4th solution

```
const contador = 1;
const div = document.querySelector('.imagens-giratorias');
const imagens = document.querySelectorAll('.imagens-giratorias img');
```

I also tried to use from [multiple selectors with document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487502/multiple-selectors-with-document-queryselectorall). No luck.

But all these solutions did not work.

#### JSFiddle

Please pay attention to two elements. While one element will always animate, another will stop of animating.

https://jsfiddle.net/gusbemacbe/mbp84u6r/2/

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @symlink, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to grab elements that have a class name starting with `imagens-giratorias`. If that's the case, use the `^` [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as shown below:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class^="imagens-giratorias"]")
```

**Update:**

Based on your update it *appears* that only one of your two divs' images is animating but in reality they're stacked on top of each of other. Feel free to use whatever layout method you want but for demonstration's sake I floated one left and the other right. Other that it was a matter of looping through your divs and assigning your function to their child images as so:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.imagens-giratórias');
var contador = 1;

var mostrarPróximo = function(div) {
  contador++;
  if (contador > 3) contador = 1;
  div.classList.remove('imagem1', 'imagem2', 'imagem3')
  div.classList.add('imagem' + contador);
};


Array.from(divs).forEach(function(div, index) {
  var images = div.querySelectorAll('img');

  Array.from(images).forEach(function(img) {
    img.addEventListener('animationend', mostrarPróximo.bind(null, div));
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1r6yjf5s/

Comment: I have tested with your answer... While it works on one element, but stops of animating on another element.

Comment: Can you tell me again what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to set the same script to the same classe for two elements. I will provide the JSFiddle.

Comment: Done, @carl-edwards. The JSFiddle code snippet is at the end of the description.

Comment: Okay so you want both to revolve simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, will it work? Or do I need to separate two different classes for each script?

Comment: Ah I see. So you're using `querySelector`, which will select the first matching element in the DOM. Try using `querySelectorAll` and looping them.

Comment: Testing with it, both elements stop of animating. Check https://jsfiddle.net/gusbemacbe/mbp84u6r/7/.

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard `Array` and `bind`. I used only `forEach`. But thank you for introducing `Array` and `bind`! But what is that `index`? According IDE's lint: «'index' is declared but its value is never read.»

Comment: Right. It's an optional parameter for `forEach`. It's the current index of the iterated element.